# ANOVA vs. mixed models

Tags: machine-learning, mixed-model, anova

I'm confused between the differences between x-way/mixed ANOVA models and mixed models. Is there a difference? If so, what is the difference and why?

Comment: @Robert Long has nice answer to this question  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234277/linear-mixed-models-and-anova

Comment: Thank you for the link!